# PostgresSQL: How to insert datetime exact as it is being sent by user?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have a Postgrest DB which is using Prisma.I am sending the data from front end as below which is inserted into the DB.

```
{
  "name": "Play Football",
  "datetime" : "2022-12-01 01:00:00"
}
```

However when I save it to DB it is getting converted to server datetime.
For e.g.

```
2022-12-01 07:20:14
```

How can I ensure that the date that is inserted stays same as what has been entered.I dont mind it getting converted for other tables but need this functionality for **only** this table.

Comment: How did your piece of SQL (the INSERT statement) look like? Check the logfiles

Comment: Use the data type `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: Even if the column's type is `timestamp WITHOUT time zone` a time of `01:00:00` wouldn't be adjusted to `07:20:14`. I guess your application is not sending the datetime value you think it sends

Comment: Can you share your schema file with the create query, this would allow to debug what could be the issue in this case?